# LINQ How to Search UNICODE Value

Tags: linq, search, unicode

Help me to search UNICODE values in LINQ, when i write a LINQ to search a string not UNICODE , it work fine but string is UNICODE, my query does not search out anything.

```
Menus.Where(e => e.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()))
     .OrderBy(e => e.Order)
     .ThenBy(e => e.Name)
     .ToList();
```

It work fine with none Unicode string like

```
"AMERICAN BREAFAST: CHOICE OF FRIED EGG OR OMELETE SERVED WITH CRISPY BACON, SAUSAGE, SAUTEED TOMATO AND TOAST"
```

but when i search a unicode string like

```
"Bữa ăn sáng kiểu Mỹ: chọn giữa trứng chiên hoặc trứng cuộn dùng kèm thịt xông khói, xúc xích, cà chua xào và bánh mì nướng"
```

it does not work anymore. please help me fix it. thanks so much

Comment: I don't get the same results. Obviously, some context is missing here, but if I call your second string.Contains("v"), it returns true. The context for each of your 'Menu' options in the 'Menus' enumerable is missing.

Comment: Strings in C# are generally unicode. Do you get you're strings from a database or a file or similar? then look into the encoding you use when you read in the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the English string you provided is actually Unicode.

Second, this category of problem has several possible loci for the source of the problem:

1. Where does "keyword" come from? Was it correctly converted from the source encoding to Unicode? If the data came from, for example, an ASP.Net application, you need to make sure that the HTML Meta Content-Type tag is "text/html; charset=UTF-8", and that the server Request and Response encoding is also defaulting to UTF-8. If you can view this variable, keyword, in the debugger without trouble, then you're probably fine.
2. What's the type of e.Name in the underlying data source? If it's on SQL Server, is it an NVARCHAR or VARCHAR? If it's VARCHAR, does the collation map to a suitable encoding that supports Vietnamese?
3. Regardless of NVARCHAR or VARCHAR, is the underlying collation also implies case sensitivity rules. If your field is using a collation that is case sensitive, your toLower call may cause unexpected results since it won't match the collation rules in the database. Additionally, the field's collation specifies whether comparisons are accent sensitive or accent insensitive, which can affect your results.
4. Under some circumstances, the Unicode normalization form may affect your results.Because Vietnamese can be represented with composed characters or decomposed letters + diacritic codepoints, you should make sure that your normalization is consistent. For example, you may find it best to encode to unicode kC or kD form, depending on your preference, but you should do that consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, however it's possible that since `string.Contains` uses the ordinal culture for comparisons, it's incorrectly matching some characters.  You may want to change your where clause to `Where(e => e.IndexOf(keyword,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)>=0)` to avoid culture issues.